# How to disiable BIGGERkeysses into an authentication application builded in django?

Tags: python, django

I want only to create users with lowercases into an authentication app login page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a [customized user model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/) that adds a validator to check if the username is written in lowercase:

```
# app_name/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

def validate_lower(value):
    if not value.islower():
        raise ValidationError(
            _('The username %(value)s should be written in lowercase'),
            params={'value': value},
        )

class User(AbstractUser):
    username_validators = [
        AbstractUser.username_validator,
        validate_lower
    ]

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=username_validators,
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
```

and then set the `User` model you defined in `app_name.User` as the user model by setting this in the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL).